# How to get the xpath selectors for each element in a UL Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to write a program that writes code for me. Imagine i have a UL list on a website and i need to scrape all the xpath selectors for each elements in the list. Is there an easy way to tell python to grab the xpath selectors for all of the elements in the UL?

For example we have this UL

```
  <ul id="test">
    <li><a href="#">Zurich</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Geneva</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Winterthur</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lausanne</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lucerne</a></li>
  </ul>
```

And i have this code in python

```
ul= driver.find_elements_by_id('test')

for element in ul:
    selector = **find the xpath/selector**
    text = element.text
```

How can i scrape the xpath for each link in the UL?

Thank you!

Edit** This is the best solution i have found but it is using several other modules. Is there any way to do this with only selenium?

lxml can auto-generate an absolute xpath for you using getpath() method.

Example (using wikipedia main page, getting xpath expression for the logo):

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree

data = urllib2.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org")
tree = etree.parse(data)
element = tree.xpath('//div[@id="p-logo"]/a')[0]
print tree.getpath(element)
```

Comment: Can you provide your desired output based on your sample html?

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below xpath:

```
li= driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@id="test"]/li')

for element in li:
    text = element.text
```

Comment: You did not understand my question.

Comment: Is there an easy way to tell python to grab the xpath selectors for all of the elements in the UL?...this is my question... have python grab XPATH for me for each element in a list. that is what i want.